# output specific HTTP header

Tags: asp.net, http

What is the code to output a specific HTTP header e.g. x-adexpert-id

Answer (score 1):

See the [Response.Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers.aspx) property.